# How can I determine if the user clicked the back button in GWTP?

Tags: java, javascript, html, gwtp, gwt-platform

I use GWTP and have two Presenters. Lets call it

- FirstPresenter
- SecondPresenter

The website starts with First. When I click a link on First I navigate to Second. Now there are two forms of navigation on the Second Presenter.

1. The user can click a link which navigates back to First
2. The user can click the browser back button.

**How can I determine if the browser back button has been clicked?**

Comment: @Gimby No, this is a different question. In my case the user does not leave the app he just navigate back to First.

Comment: In that case the user does not leave the app; he just navigates back to another page. It seems to apply directly to your question.